# Find coordinates of intersection of vector and a square's edges

Tags: geometry

Not big problem, but I can't find a formula for the following stuff.

I have this kind of things:

[image]

(I was not able to draw vector in my application so I represented the source by point and the end of the arrow by nothing, and the vector is the segment) ; also don't pay attention the red ones on this image)

So I'll have a lot of vectors composed of a source point (**inside** the square) and a destination point (**inside** or **outside** the square).

The square is delimited by the four black points in the corners.

I need a formula to get the coordinates of the intersection with the edge (if there is one).

For example I'd need the coordinates of the "points" on the following image:

[image]

Anybody has an idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: It is not clear how you define the red vectors and how they relate to the black vectors in the other drawing. You have 5 red vectors(?) in the square...

Comment: Just edited my post.

Comment: In your case, the direction seems to be irrelevant. Is there no reason you don't work with segments? (Also, note that vectors typically have magnitude and direction, but not a starting point - they can be "moved around" and still be the same vector).

Comment: Yes I just don't know how to call a vector with a starting point, maybe a translation? I figured out a formula by myself anyways, I was a bit tired, that was not that hard finally sorry to annoye ans thanks.

Comment: And yes direction was irrelevant you were right.

Comment: It seems that most of the segments are inside your "square". Are you interested in those that cross the edge? All the crossings are actually on the right side only - right? You may use a test that for each segment will tell you if it crosses a certain edge (there cases in which two are crossed). Are you looking for those test where the segment edges are given? Doing the test for each segment separately?

Comment: How you represent the edge of a segment coordinates? integers between 0 and 255? This is a hint for the solution:)

Comment: Most of them are inside but some will cross one of the 4 edges, not just to the right. Actually I made a algorithm but I'm struggling on the last test, I think I'll ask in a new question because I asked 2D to simplify but it was for 3D, thanks again.

Comment: The technique for 2D or 3D could be basically the same - I am not sure I will see you 3D question - could you add a link to it?